# Many to Many relationship code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Hi I'm trying to create a database in MVC containing a list of Tv shows and Actors associated with them.
Each Tv show can have multiple Actors and an actor can appear on many tv shows. Each actor has a cast name too, for each show they appear in. Here's my models.

```
      public class TvShow
{
    public int ShowId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Actor> cast { get; set; }

}

public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TvShow> shows { get; set; }
}

public class Cast
{
    public int ShowId { get; set; }
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string CastName { get; set; }
}

public class TvContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TvShow> Shows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

I query the database and run the application to create the database for me, but the CastName attribute is not appearing in my linker table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can EF know that you want to use entity Cast as a M:N relation table?

You have to link entity Cast from TvShow and Actor entities when you want to have there an additional property on many to many relationship. So the model can look like this:

```
public class TvShow
{
    public int ShowId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Cast> Casts { get; set; }

}

public class Actor
{
    public int ActorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Cast> Shows { get; set; }
}

public class Cast
{       
    public string CastName { get; set; }
    public TvShow TwShow { get; set; }
    public Actor Actor { get; set; }
}
```

And you can get list of actors for given TvShow with following query:

```
twShow.Casts.Select(c => c.Actor);
```